# SimpleModal jQuery Plugin - Hide/Disable Loading Thingy?

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

Greetings!

I'm using this excellent jQuery plugin and would like to know how to disable or hide the loading thing that appears when the pointer is moved outside the box.

You can see this on the Demos page:

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/

However, if you try the examples on this page ("Examples"), the loading thing doesn't appear:

www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/#examples
(Sorry but as a new user, I can't post more than one hyperlink (!))

Your ideas and suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try tracing the CSS style of the overlay DIV (the grayed out area) to see where the cursor gets set.

By looking at the sample project which I downloaded you need to look in basic.css at #simplemodal-overlay and change cursor:wait; to what you need.

Comment: Bingo!  Changing cursor to 'default' does the trick. Thanks Dieter G